# Facebook API on iPhone: How to compare two sets of returned status updates

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, nsmutablearray, compare

I am building an app where I need the status updates of the user. I am putting the status updates into an array, and displaying them to the user for him to select. I am able to gather the data, parse the data from JSON and place it into an array. However, every once in a while, I would like to check if there are any new status updates posted. The way I would like to do that is place the new status into a new array, and see where the new statuses end, and where the existing ones start. I am doing that by checking for the first string in the old status array, and seeing where it is in the new array. The location of the first old status in the new array allows me to tell how many new statuses are present. I am able to do this perfectly with the Twitter API, but am facing difficulties with Graph API. Gathering data for the first time works perfectly, and when there are no new statuses, the code works. The problem is when a new status is posted. My code for gathering and comparing the data is:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{   
    NSMutableArray *goodstatusesFB = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *datafromFB = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *stringfromFB = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *json = [stringfromFB JSONValue];
    NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
    for (int a = 0; a < [items count]; a++)
    {
        NSDictionary *tempdict = [items objectAtIndex:a];
        NSString *typeFB = [tempdict objectForKey:@"type"];
        if ([typeFB isEqualToString:@"status"])
        {
            [datafromFB addObject:tempdict];
        }   
    }
    if ([goodstatusesFBexisting count] == 0)
    {
        //First time loading FB statuses
        [goodstatusesFBexisting addObjectsFromArray:goodstatusesFB];
    }
    else
    {
        //Existing statuses
        NSDictionary *statusDictold = [goodstatusesFBexisting objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDictionary *statusDictnew = [goodstatusesFB objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *messageold = [statusDictold objectForKey:@"message"];
        NSString *messagenew = [statusDictnew objectForKey:@"message"];
        if ([messagenew isEqualToString:messageold])
        {
            NSLog(@"No new messages");
        }//Works perfectly until here!
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"New messages!"); 
            NSMutableArray *textfromFB = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *textfromnew = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            int numberofnewFB = 0;

            for (int a = 0; a < [goodstatusesFBexisting count]; a++)
            {
                NSDictionary *newcontents = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
                newcontents = [goodstatusesFBexisting objectAtIndex:a];
                NSString *textfromexisting = [newcontents objectForKey:@"message"];
                [textfromFB insertObject:textfromexisting atIndex:a];      
            }   
            for (int b = 0; b < [goodstatusesFB count]; b++)
            {
                NSDictionary *newcontents1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
                newcontents1 = [goodstatusesFB objectAtIndex:b];
                NSString *textfromexisting = [newcontents1 objectForKey:@"message"];
                [textfromnew insertObject:textfromexisting atIndex:b];       
            }
            numberofnewFB = [textfromnew indexOfObject:messageold];
            NSLog(@"You have %i new statuses", numberofnewFB);        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure messageold is being added to textfromnew? Try printing the array and see if it is in there. I'm not sure you add it.